# The question "Same again?"

Tags: meaning

> If it starts to rain just as you have to leave your house, that is
>   unfortunate. But if you have to go out, apart from putting on a
>   raincoat or getting your umbrella, or cancelling your appointment,
>   there isn’t much you can do about it. You can’t stop the rain no
>   matter how much you want to. Should you be upset about this? Or should
>   you just be philosophical? ‘Being philosophical’ simply means
>   accepting what you can’t change. What about the inevitable process of
>   growing older and the shortness of life? How should you feel about
>   these features of the human condition? Same again?

[A little history of philosophy, Nigel Warburton]

I don't understand of the question "Same again?" in the context. Could you explain it to me? 
I think it means "Being philosophical again? Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "Same again?" is referring back to the answer you gave about how you would respond to rain -- "Should you be upset about this? Or should you just be philosophical?" -- and asking if you can give the same answer to something as serious as the inevitability of death.

In the first case, the rain, most people would say you should be philosophical about the rain; it's not something you can fix, so just let it happen and deal with the consequences.  The second case, inevitable aging and death, is just as un-fixable, but most people aren't nearly as calmly rational about it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it means "unchanged (about how to feel), still the same". It is ironic because the question should always be upsetting, indeed. At the same time, you might be correct, that it means "Being philosophical", if that's to be upset, and if asking "same again?" is a mild expression of astonishment. The crux is that we can't change that we can't accept that we can't change that we grow old, but at the same time we have to acknowledge that we can't change that we change.

When I read the title question, I thought it relates to ordering, "I'll have the same again". I'm not sure how that fits in. Most likely the author got hungry after having a deep think.